# Using jsPlumb library in lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning, libraries

I'm trying to get jsPlumb to work inside a lightning component and I'm stuck in the beginning (https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/home.html#container). When I try to initialize container, i get errors: "Container is not at eval". I guess it has something to do with locker service and access to a specific div with its ID? Is there any workaround on this?

I've got quite a lot of code, but in general I have a div with a specific id=mainContainer, inside that div i have some elements that I want to connect with jsPlumb magic - to do so, I need to provide to library the parent element of those elements, I guess that would be my 'mainContaier'. I tried couple different things, including setting aura:id and getting element with 'component.find() etc. I'm basically out of ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggest you use your browser’s Developer Tools to debug this. The problem could either be in the library or in your use of the library.